# Why is MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification only getting dispatched once for my many instances of my MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I've got a UITableView which lists movie files from on disk.  For each cell row, there is a worker instance  allocated for each visible row, used to generate a thumbnail for the movie file and get its duration to display in the row.

For each instance of MPMoviePlayerController in the worker class Im listening for a MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification event from the movie player.  For some reason this event only seems to be dispatched (or at least Im only able to catch it) from one of the worker instances.  Here is the init and listener code.  There are a few comments inline.

```
- (id) initWithRequestAsset:(RequestAsset *)asset {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.requestAsset = asset;
    self.moviePlayer = [MPMoviePlayerController alloc];
    [self setupMoviePlayerListeners];
    [self.moviePlayer initWithContentURL:self.requestAsset.urlPath];
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;

    //  I've also tried to retain the moviePlayer, to no avail
    [self.moviePlayer release];
}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void) setupMoviePlayerListeners {
//
// If the object: is set to nil then Im able to catch three notifications, but they are all from last instance of the MPMoviePlayerController
//
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onMovieDurationAvailable:)
                                             name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer];
```

}

```
- (void) onMovieDurationAvailable:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"duration received notification");

self.requestAsset.duration = [[notification object] duration];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
```

}

What am I doing wrong?  I figured if I were to set the object: parameter to the instance of the MPMoviePlayerController it would allow me to get only the event for that instance.  However, it appears that Im only getting the last notification dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 active MPMoviePlayerController instance. You can create multiple but only 1 will work at a time.

See (about 2 screens down):
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

"Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie."